# Docker container lost file after restart docker service or reboot

Tags: docker, permissions, rsync

My server's main drive nearly full. So I move `/var/lib/docker` directory to second drive location `/media/my-username/sec-drive/docker` using

```
sudo -s # enter root mode
service docker stop
rsync -aXS /media/my-username/sec-drive/docker /var/lib/docker
rm -rf /var/lib/docker
ln -s /media/my-username/sec-drive/docker /var/lib/docker
serivce docker start
```

then I start my all docker container by using `docker-compose up -d`
all containers works just fine.

But when I reboot or restart docker service, one of my containers lost a bunch of files(other containsers works just fine). One of those files is `libmxnet.so`(filemode:777) under `/opt/myproj/mxnet/`

```
use local mxnet
RuntimeError: Cannot find the files.
List of candidates:
/opt/myproj/mxnet/libmxnet.so
/opt/myproj/mxnet/libmxnet.so
/opt/myproj/mxnet/../../build/libmxnet.so
/usr/local/nvidia/lib/libmxnet.so
/usr/local/nvidia/lib64/libmxnet.so
../../../libmxnet.so
```

Those files seems lost randomly. In mxnet folder `__init__.py` lost but `__init__.pyc` stays fine. That's really wired.

Then I try to remove images and containers and import again, just turn out same result.

**UPDATE:**

This error occurred on another server again. But this time I've reinstalled the system and haven't move docker to another drive. Seems it has nothing to do with docker directory location

Comment: If this happened to me, I'd probably delete everything in both copies of `/var/lib/docker` and start over, re-running `docker build` and/or `docker pull` as needed to get my images back.

Comment: @DavidMaze I've tried removing all files under /var/lib/docker and `docker load` images, not fixed. thx 4 reply

Answer (score 0):

You have to instruct the docker daemon that you change the folder.

In your `docker.service` you should add a parameter (-g):

```
FROM:
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon 
TO:
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -g /new/path/docker
```

Some references here:

https://www.rb-associates.co.uk/blog/move-var-lib-docker-to-another-directory/

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-move-docker-s-default-var-lib-docker-to-another-directory-on-ubuntu-debian-linux

Comment: I already used a soft link `ln -s /media/my-username/sec-drive/docker /var/lib/docker`. Did you mean that is the reason caused problem? I will try your solution and comment again. Thx very much.

Comment: I remember I used softlink. It's not the problem. For me it was the proper parameter to pass to the demon.

Comment: This error occurred on another server again. But this time I've reinstalled the system and haven't move docker to another drive. Seems it has nothing to do with docker directory location.